# How to set the single background image for bothe view and tabeview

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one applciation.In that i added the one tableview to present view.I added the background image for present view.ANd whenever tableview add to view,tableview override the view and that background image  not appeared.But i need to dispaly only that tablecell content on that view with that background.So please tell me how to solve this one.

Comment: set the background of view and clear the background color of the tableview

Comment: Set your `tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to clear the background color for UITableView.

```
tableviewObj.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

If this is not working, please post your sample code for our reference. Thanks.

Comment: Thnx for repeating my answer!

Comment: Mr.Sharjeel Sorry friend. I didn't copied your answer at all. I just post my own answer for this question. I didn't seen your answer before i add my answer for this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the background Color for your table view to 'Clear Color' either through xib or through code.
In your **viewDidLoad** method write:

```
yourTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Tell me if it helps!